# Compiled with `coffee` stopped working

Tags: node.js, npm, coffeescript

I'm not sure what I've done, but I can no longer compile CoffeeScript files. I keep getting the following, regardless of which file I'm trying to compile. I've tried reinstalling coffee by running `sudo npm remove --global coffeescript` and then `sudo npm install --global coffeescript`. Automatic compilation in Atom using the `coffee-compile` package still works. How can I resolve this?

```
user@computer:~/some/path $ coffee -c code.coffee 
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffeescript/lib/coffeescript/command.js:23
  ({spawn, exec} = require('child_process'));
   ^

ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffeescript/bin/coffee:15:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the same on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, fixed simply by

```
$ sudo npm remove --global coffeescript
$ sudo apt-get install coffeescript
```

Comment: When I do that, I get `coffeescript is already the newest version (1.9.3~dfsg-1).` Then when I run `coffee -c code.coffee`, I get `bash: /usr/local/bin/coffee: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Could that be you have a broken symlink in /usr/local/bin/ ? Try /usr/bin/coffee -c code.coffee

Comment: If that fails `apt-get purge coffeescript` and reinstall. Check where coffee was actually installed (`dpkg-query -L coffeescript`) and why bash looks for it in different place

Comment: `/usr/bin/coffee -c code.coffee` works. Should I just `ln -s  /usr/bin/coffee /usr/local/bin/coffee`?

Comment: Yes, or simply remove the broken link `/usr/local/bin/coffee`, bash should pick the correct path then.

Answer (score 1):

You have CoffeeScript 2+ installed, which requires Node 6 or later; but your Node runtime is < 6. (The error specifically is that the Node runtime chokes on the `({spawn, exec} =` destructuring syntax, which Node < 6 doesn’t understand.) Either install CoffeeScript 1.x or Node 6+.